# How to get Waze alerts in Google Navigation?

Tags: gps, google-maps-navigation, alerts

I'm new to Android and I like Google Navigation. I really appreciate how the indications are displayed and how the application works.

I also discovered Waze, which is a very convenient app to show alerts that other drivers report.

I've seen Google Navigation sometime displays some Waze alerts as tiny icons, but is there any nice way to use Google Navigation as a GPS and hear Waze sounds and display alerts? (Accidents, traffic jams, police...).

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: They've only just started to integrate Waze functionality into Google Maps, and vice versa. The functionality you're looking for is _probably_ coming.

Comment: FYE: http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2013/08/new-features-ahead-google-maps-and-waze.html

Comment: @AlEverett : This is what I have for the moment but it's not very visible and I don't hear alerts...

Comment: I have both loaded, but always use GMaps, and as of today the Waze alerts are appearing in Gmaps. I didn't do anything to make it happen. Doesn't look like I can create a Waze alert from within Gmaps though. That would be nice.

Comment: @EricHiggins, is there a sound every time you get close to an accident or other alert?

Comment: No sounds, but icons appear on the Gmaps route. Then you can click on the icon and see the detail, i.e. "traffic incident". And it notes in the pop up it was applied by the Waze app. Pretty cool.

Comment: Ok, that's not very convenient as you have to keep an eye on the map. I also experienced disappearing alerts on some levels of zoom. Not very practical. Let's wait and see :)

Comment: @everyone Anyone who has *not* installed the `Waze` app seeing `Waze` notifications in `GMaps` ? If so, where / how ?